# how to make leaflet map height variable

Tags: css, leaflet

In my Application I was making div of map as

```
<div id="map" style="height: 610px; width:100%"></div>
```

but to make my map responsive I want to make height also 100%, if I make `height: 100%` then it is not working.

How can I make height also variable like width so that map can be seen properly on any device.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/CcYp6/

If you change height & width of map then you will not get map.

Comment: Provide JSfiddle of your code as well as the screenshot of how you want.

Comment: @NathanLee please see above demo

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to set the parent elements to `height: 100%;` first

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8m7z/)

[<strike>Demo</strike>](http://jsfiddle.net/y8m7z/1/) (This won't work as no parent height is defined)

Explanation: Why do you need to do that? So when you specify an element's height in `%` then the 1st question that arises is: `100%` of what? 
By default, a div has height of `0px`, so `100%` for a div simply won't work, but setting the parent elements `height` to `100%;` will work.

Comment: can you explane little bit ?

Comment: It may work in normal condition. But as my div contains map it want work.

Comment: @vaibhavshah Which map are you talking about?

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam Explained :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am using leaflet map

Answer (score 28):

You have to set the div size with JavaScript.

```
$("#map").height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());
map.invalidateSize();
```

You can find a complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPEaV/).

Comment: how to add one more attribute as padding from left in $("#map").height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());

Comment: @vaibhav shah, you could accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found this necessary. CSS does the trick.

Answer (score 18):

Use height="100vh" works in newer browser. but its ok.

Comment: I also combined this with CSS Media Queries and fantastic ;)

Answer (score 2):

Put a `position: relative` wrapper parent around it, then position your map absolutely to fill that parent:

```
.map-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

If `#map` already has a parent that you can position relatively, just use that; you won't need the `.map-wrapper` element.

[Leaflet Quick Start Guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) could be clearer on this point as it's a common use case. The [mobile tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/) hints at it.

Comment: Thanks for the mobile tutorial link, it solved my issue!