# PureCSS.io menu & Leaflet page height

Tags: css, leaflet, yui-pure-css

I'm trying to create a fullscreen map with [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and a [purecss](http://purecss.io/menus/) horizontal menu on top of it.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543446/how-to-make-leaflet-map-height-variable) is a solution for making the map height 100% (set parent elements also to 100% height).
So right now, I've got something like this:

```
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">map</a>
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Map -->
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is: the page height ist 100% + the height of the menu. So parts of the map get cut off at the bottom.
I used Firefox' Inspector and changed various CSS settings to no avail. I also tested different browsers to exclude a problem with Firefox. What am I missing? Unfortunately I'm not a CSS guy..

I created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jygzLf3v/13/

The result window is scrollable for the height of the menu but should be "fullscreen" including the menu. 
Thanks for some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use `#map {height:calc(100% - $HEIGHT_OF_MENU);}` on your  map container to size things up properly, and not have any cutoff.Don't forget to add 'px' after your menu height.

Comment: Menu height is given in em, so the height of the menu is not static ([link](https://github.com/yahoo/pure/blob/master/src/menus/css/menus-skin.css)). What looks good in my browser could be worse in yours?

Comment: I just realised calc() can calculate with em, too. Will give this a try.

Comment: Tested it. As soon as you don't use a standard font or standard font size in your browser this will break. :-/

Comment: Are you not able to switch it to something more fixed/arbitrary?

Comment: Yeah, since I only want a small menu with few buttons I consider giving up on purecss and use [EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) instead. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You cand simply add `overflow: hidden` to your body element, in the stylesheet.

http://jsfiddle.net/jygzLf3v/14/

Comment: This will still cutoff the map. I did not mention it but I have a ZoomControl in the bottom left position which also will get cut off. http://jsfiddle.net/jygzLf3v/15/